# Are most of screens and devices able to play videos at 60 HZ?

Tags: video, youtube

I'm talking about the devices that are able to play youtube videos. I created a youtube video that requires to work at 60Hz. When I shared the video on youtube, some people said that the video doesn't work. It turns out to be that sometimes youtube shows the option **720p60** for some devices. Other devices have the **720p** option but they don't play at 60 Hz so the video doesn't work as expected.

Why does that happen? Aren't most of the devices capable of playing 60 Hz these days?

Comment: Keep in mind that 60Hz is not just a higher refresh rate. The device behind it also needs to be fast enough to process twice the amount of data in the same time. Because of this, users and even youtube may switch back to 30 hz. This also costs twice the bandwidth. Another reason one might choose to keep 30hz as their default setting, especially on mobile devices that are not connected to wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make assumptions about frame rates of end users, especially if those users are using "normal" TVs.

Most TVs work at either 24 or 30Hz when viewing video content. They may be capable of operating at 60Hz or even 100Hz, but for faithful playback of video content they should work at the native rate of the video. Most commonly that is, as mentioned, 24 or 30Hz.

Also a 4K display over a [HDMI 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4) cable may well be actively limited to 24Hz or 30Hz.

720p60 also uses extra bandwidth over 30Hz, so on low bandwidth links YouTube might fall back to the lower rate.